# Time series prediction

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, multiple-regression, markov-process

I have data having companies details with how many position opened on particular date and their due date.I want to find likelihood of requirement on which particular time/season (if I take month) company requires candidates for which position? Which type of machine learning algorithm should I use?
 For example,

[image]

From above data I want to find on the month of June 2016 which companies required how many candidates for which positions?

Comment: I propose to close this question as it is not precise enough. If you go into more detail I will withdraw my flag

Comment: Furthermore you might have a try with a VAR Model or a Kalman Filter or a recurrent neural network. That depends on your data structure.